# how to create show password button QTdesigner

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

how could i create a button that shows password in qtdesigner and python?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your button to a slot like this one:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def toggle_password_hint(self):
    if self.<yourQLineEdit>.echoMode() == QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal:
        self.<yourQLineEdit>.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
    else:
         self.<yourQLineEdit>.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal)
```